# Load Tab seperated Format txt file into Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to load a tab seperated file into hbase. I get the error as mentioned in the screen shot please advise.

File Contents:

```
2   1/1/16 0:29 1/1/16 0:39
2   1/1/16 0:19 1/1/16 0:39
2   1/1/16 0:19 1/1/16 0:39
2   1/1/16 0:22 1/1/16 0:38
2   1/1/16 0:24 1/1/16 0:39
2   1/1/16 0:32 1/1/16 0:39
```

query:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns= HBASE_ROW_KEY,id,date:c1,date:c2 sample1 hdfs://localhost:9000/FinalProject/Hbase/samplehbase.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not execute the `Importsv` statement inside `hbase shell`.

```
hbase(main)> create 'sample1', 'date'
```

---

```
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,id,date:c1,date:c2"
```

The `sample1` table has only one column family `date`. `id` is not a column family, remove it from `columns`.

Try,

```
~$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,date:c1,date:c2" sample1 hdfs://localhost:9000/FinalProject/Hbase/samplehbase.txt
```

And in your sample data, all the records have same row key. On import, only the last row will be persisted in the table as the `VERSIONS => 1` by default for the column family. Consider increasing the `VERSIONS` before running the import.

```
hbase(main)> alter 'sample1',{NAME=>'date',VERSIONS=>6}
```

Comment: Can you assist me in creating index for hbase table?